# Successive pictures on R

Tags: r, video, plot

I have a code to plot a world map with a meteorological field for one moment (or one measure). 
Is it possible to successively plot the map for different moments (for i from 1 to 125) in order to view a sort of video when we run the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, look at the [animation](http://cran.r-project.org/package=animation) package.

It can creates an animated gif for you (as well as other tricks).  There [are live examples](http://vis.supstat.com/categories.html#Animation-ref) you can look at as eg [Buffon's needle](http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/buffons-needle), a [CLT demo](http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/central-limit-theorem) and much more.

The package abstracts away some of the OS-dependent layers. If you know the basics, you can of course just call the corresponding tool from the [imagemagick project](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which is likely to be available on OS of choice too.

Comment: Works! The only problem is that the image is not smooth on screen but I am aware than it is not the main function of R!

Comment: That might be device-depedent too, so it worth trying a few things.  The docs / mailing list may have pointers.